# How do I make my React/Bootstrap 4 validation error visible?

Tags: reactjs, validation, bootstrap-4, visible

I'm using React 16.13.0 and Bootstrap 4.  I have a React component (src/components/Input.jsx),

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormControl, FormLabel} from 'react-bootstrap';

const Input = (props) => {
    return (
  <div className="form-group">
      <FormLabel>{props.title}</FormLabel>
      <FormControl
            type={props.type}
            id={props.name}
            name={props.name}
            value={props.value}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
          />

      {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
          <FormControl.Feedback>
                 {props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => ( 
                     <div key={`field-error-${props.name}-${index}`} className="fieldError">{error}</div>
                 ))} 
          </FormControl.Feedback>
      )}
  </div>
    )
}
```

export default Input;

in which I'd like to display an error message if their is a form validation error returned from form submission.

```
  async handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const NC = this.state.newCoop;
    delete NC.address.country;

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/coops/',{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      });
      
      if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log('_result_: ', result);
        return result;
      }
      throw await response.json();
    } catch (errors) {
      console.log('_error_: ', errors);
      this.setState({ errors });
    }
  }
```

However, when there is an error, although I can see in my HTML that the DIV with the error message is present, it is not visible.  What am I missing?  I'm guessing bootstrap provides some standard way of making my element visible.

Comment: Any online demo?

Comment: Finally, I have something up.  If you visit http://prod.chicommons.coop/ and enter an incomplete US phone number, e.g. "12345", you'll see the POST request fail in the dev console and you'll see an "_error_:  {phone: Array(1), web_site: Array(1)}" console message output.  If you inspect beneath the phone number field, you can see the HTML for the error, but it is not visible.  Figure I have just misconfigured something in bootstrap, but not sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get visible error feedback, set `isInvalid={Boolean(props.errors[props.name])}` for `FormControl` and `type="invalid"` for `FormControl.Feedback`.

Consider destructuring the props to simplify your code.

Comment: You actually meant to include a closed parens, no?  Anyway, I edited my question to include the results of what I think you are suggesting I do (error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined").  Let me know if that was what you meant.

Comment: Whoops, I did mean to include closed parens. Oh and you do need the `props.errors &&` check as well or if possible, use Optional chaining.

Comment: Winner!  Can't believe that turned out to be as hard as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting error state incorrectly? In your comments, the server returns `"error: {phone: Array(1), web_site: Array(1)}"` and you are setting state like this `this.setState({ errors })`. With this, your `error` state will still be your initial state.

Try something like `this.setState({ errors: response.error })`

Comment: Oh my comment about "error: {phone: Array(1), web_site: Array(1)}" just meant that the console.log was confirming an error was returned from the server.  The error message HTML is getting added beneath the element in question (inspector confirms this), the problem is that the error message HTML just isn't visible.  I don't know enough about bootstrap 4 to know what else I need to do to make the message visible.